# Solve Double Integral Using Change of Variables: $\int^1_0 \int^{y^2}_0 {y\cos(x-y^2)dxdy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently learning about Jacobians, and I need help on the following integral:

$$\int^1_0 \int^{y^2}_0 {y\cos(x-y^2)dxdy}$$

The first thought that came to my mind was change of variables, because I read in my textbook that when dealing with these kinds of problems, it is best to do so. Is this right? How do I utilize this to solve this double integral?

Comment: The substitution $u=y^{2}$ seems like a very helpful one!

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Yes, I thought about that. But I don't know how to proceed with that. I'm very knew to multivariable calculus, so pardon my little understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

> $$
> \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} y \cos(x-y^2) dx dy.
> $$

Simply perform the integration:

> $$
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} y \cos(x-y^2) dx dy
> &=& \displaystyle \int_0^1 \left\{ \int_0^{y^2} y \cos(x-y^2) dx \right\} dy\\
> &=& \displaystyle \int_0^1 \Big[ y \sin(x-y^2) \Big]_0^{y^2} dy\\
> &=& \displaystyle \int_0^1 \Big\{ y \sin(y^2-y^2)
>         - y \sin(-y^2) \Big\} dy\\
> &=& \displaystyle \int_0^1 y \sin(y^2) dy\\
> &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sin(y^2) d\big(y^2\big)\\
> &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sin(z) dz\\
> &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \Big[ - \cos(z) \Big]_0^1\\
> &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \big( 1 - \cos(1) \big).\\
> \end{array}
> $$

So the final result is

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
> \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} y \cos(x-y^2) dx dy
> = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1 - \cos(1) \big)}
> $$

Comment: Can downvoter explain why?

Comment: Didn't downvote but OP asked for a method using change of variables.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a Jacobian problem.  You don't need to change your variables of integration, except for $u$-substitutions.  Observe that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 y \left (\int_0^{y^2} \cos (x-y^2) dx\right ) dy & = & \int_0^1 y \left ( \sin (x- y^2) |_0^{y^2} \right ) dy \\
& = & \int_0^1 y(\sin 0 - \sin(-y^2)) dy \\
& = & \int_0^1 y\sin (y^2) dy.
\end{eqnarray*}

The rest should be straight-forward.

Comment: Is it just integration by parts now?

Comment: @BobbieIsaly No.  Use Daniel Littlewood's suggestion from the comments above.